# TinyMCE - Click outside

Tags: jquery, focus, tinymce, blur

I would like to use the JQuery implementation of TinyMCE, I've downloaded the demo and this is working fine.

What I'd like to do is make any textarea (could have a common class) dynamically turn into an TinyMCE editor when clicked and then revert back to a textbox when clicked outside (lost focus).

I have tweaked the demo code and can make it convert into a TinyMCE editor when clicked on but can't make it revert back when clicked outside - please could anyone assist with this.

Here is the code below, I have left out any attempts of reverting back.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Full featured example using jQuery plugin</title>

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>

<!-- Load TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $('.tinymce').focus(function(){

        $(this).tinymce({
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

            // General options
            theme : "advanced",
                plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css : "css/content.css",

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
            });                     

    });


    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/dump.php?example=true">
    <div>
        <h3>Full featured example using jQuery plugin</h3>

        <p>
            This example shows how TinyMCE can be lazy loaded using jQuery. The jQuery plugin will also attach it's self to various jQuery methods to make it more easy to get/set editor contents etc.
        </p>

        <!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%" class="tinymce">
                &lt;p&gt;
                    This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
                &lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;
                Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.
                &lt;/p&gt;
            </textarea>


        </div>

        <!-- Some integration calls -->
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().show();return false;">[Show]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().hide();return false;">[Hide]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('Bold');return false;">[Bold]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').html());return false;">[Get contents]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getContent());return false;">[Get selected HTML]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));return false;">[Get selected text]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getNode().nodeName);return false;">[Get selected element]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<b>Hello world!!</b>');return false;">[Insert HTML]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<b>{$selection}</b>');return false;">[Replace selection]</a>

        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.tinymce').blur(function() {
    $(this).tinymce().execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, this.id);
});
```

Comment: Still no joy but thanks, I tried changing to $('.tinymce').live('blur', function etc. etc. a it's dynamically generated but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
tinymce.dom.Event.add(editor.getBody(), "blur", function (e) {
//your Statements here
});
```